# How to have more than 32 namepaces in aerospike?

Tags: namespaces, max, limit, aerospike

There is max limit of 32 to the namespace count in aerospike.
Is it possible to have more than 32 namespaces in an aerospike?

Answer (score 2):

One Aerospike cluster only supports 32 namespaces and 1023 sets per namespace. Please read Aerospike’s FAQ [here](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/FAQ.html).

Are you asking because you have a very large number of tables (sets)? Please let me know your concern.

Comment: Actually in my case a single aerospike cluster is used by many apps. And now we have reached the limit of 32 namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Think of a namespace as a policy container, similar to TABLESPACE, which most importantly defines the storage for the data within it. The [storage engine](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage/) can be memory or an SSD or in-memory with HDD persistence. Do you have more than 32 SSDs in your database nodes?

This is less a 'database' (in RDBMS terms) than a tablespace, but I doubt many people have 32 databases even in RDBMS land.